# Deleting iCloud contents locally

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro, macos

I haven't really ever intentionally used iCloud; however, upon browsing ~/Library/Mobile Documents, I noticed that I must have unintentionally saved several files to iCloud.

Unfortunately, I can't remember any of my password/security credentials--or even the email address--I provided when I set up the facility. I'm pretty much resigned to the fact that I'm not going to be able to recover any of these credentials (unless somebody provides some untried suggestion), rendering the account pretty much useless.

As a result, I'd like to remove all documents saved in error to iCloud. Can this be done locally without the credentials?
Will deleting files from ~/Library/Mobile Documents delete files from iCloud too or just locally (on my MacBook)?

Comment: Have a look at Settings -> iCloud to see whether you are still logged into iCloud. If yes, you'll find your AppleID under "Account Details"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting files from Mobile Documents will delete them from iCloud if you are currently signed in to iCloud and the Documents & Data service is active.

If you are not currently signed in, you can delete the files to reclaim local space but this will not delete the files from iCloud.

Comment: I don't want to deviate from the original topic, but it turns out that I am signed into my iCloud account; given this, is there anyway to retrieve--or reset--my password locally without my original password/security credentials?

Comment: @user9171 No, simply being logged in doesn't let you reset a password, else this would be a security risk if you accidentally left yourself logged in somewhere and someone gained access. The only way to reset a forgotten password is to go to [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com/) and follow the instructions, or phone Apple Support.